# Adding Outlets in Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, xcode4

I'm creating IBOutlets by dragging a UI component from within the XIB editor into my view controller's header file. I'm dragging and dropping within the curly braces so that they are simply treated as instance variables and not properties. However, in spite of this I noticed release statements in my viewDidUnload and dealloc methods. Isn't this unnecessary? Like I said, these are not properties I'm creating. Why is the code being generated to release these objects when there is no retain, alloc, copy etc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS, if an outlet is declared to be an ivar instead of a property, you are responsible for releasing it at the appropriate times (i.e. in `-dealloc` and in `-viewDidUnload`. You should also set them to `nil` in the latter.)

This is due to a quirk of memory management on iOS. Regardless, my personal preference is to avoid using `readwrite` properties for outlets, because IMHO it breaks the view controller's encapsulation in a bad way.

Comment: What I dont understand is why should I release an outlet if I havent allocated, or retained, or copied it?

Comment: Normally you wouldn't. This is a rare exception. Your `release` balances the `retain` or `alloc` done when the Nib was decoded.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is that all of your outlets should be retained properties. That way all of the views subviews (your buttons etc.) will be guaranteed to live longer than the view itself. I have never heard of coding in the way you have. Usually you just type the code and connect your outlets in the .xib.

Comment: Really? Well I thought the same earlier on but then I came across this book :  iPhone SDK Development by Bill Dudney and Chris Adamson. In most of the examples they do not declare IBOutlets as properties !!

Comment: Check out the Apple docs. Scroll halfway down this page where it talks about outlets. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/05_ConfiguringView.html. You can also look on this page where they talk about setting the view controller as a property to make sure it lives as long as the application does. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/03_AddingViewController.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007514-CH5-SW1. It's the same with subviews. You don't want one dealloc'd with your view onscreen

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make them properties, Objective-C before 2.0 didn't include properties, properties are just syntactic sugar.

they are retained when they are pulled out of the nib.

check out [The Nib Object Life Cycle](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html) section